# Insert entry in WinEdt 8.1

Tags: winedt

How can I create a `Insert` menu entry for a new environment I created. For example, one can insert a figure by going to `Insert > Objects > Figure`. Of course, custom environments can be gotten by going to `Insert > Environments > New Environment` but I would like one that I can activate via a shortcut like `CTRL+ALT+E` or the like and even from the menu tab `Insert`. The result should look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this WinEdt macro, which inserts what you want on a new line in WinEdt:

```
BeginGroup;
InsLine;
NewLine;
Mark(1);
Ins("\begin{example}{}%");
InsLine;
Indent;
InsertBullet;
InsLine;
Ins("\begin{solution}%");
InsLine;
Indent;
InsertBullet;
InsLine;
Unindent;
Ins("\end{solution}%");
InsLine;
Unindent;
Ins("\end{example}");
Goto(1);
NextBullet;
EndGroup;
```

Save it as `example.edt`  in, say, `%b\Local\Macros\`. Then add to `%b\ConfigEx\MainMenu.ini` (you can edit it from the `Options Interface`), the following lines just between line 1332 (`ITEM="-"`) and line 1333 (`SUBMENU="Font>"`):

```
  SUBMENU="Personal>"
      CAPTION="&Personal"
      CONFIG_FILTER="Default;MiKTeX;TeX Live;HTML"
      REQ_DOCUMENT=1
    ITEM="Example"
      CAPTION="&Example"
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Local\Macros\example.edt');"
      REQ_DOCUMENT=1
  END="Personal>"
  ITEM="-"
```

Final step: save the new MainMenu.ini on clicking on the  `leftmost icon` in the Options Interface, so that the modifications be written in WinEdt.dnt. You'll then have access to the macro example.edt either from the `Insert -> Personal` submenu, or with the `Alt+I+P+E` shortcut.

Let me know if it doesn't work fine: it might depend on personal configurations, though I don't think so.

Comment: Probably so. That's not very important. Actually I inserted it just before the first submenu in the `Insert` menu. I also could write a painless installation/deinstallation.  procedure, if you wish. You also can add a "Personal" `menu` in `MainMenu.ini`, but the access through a shortcut will not be so self evident.

Comment: If you cannot save the edit, it's probably there is a faulty syntax like a spurious character/space or something. Could you send (a link to) a fragment of your MainMenu.ini that contains the copy of my code?

Comment: Did you save it  by clicking the `leftmost icon` in the Options Interface? It's necessary so that it be written in `WinEdt.dnt`, which is the file that WinEt reads to update its configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14981/discussion-between-bernard-and-azetina).

Comment: Works fine now thanks. Could you update your answer so that it includes the last remark you wrote about clicking on the left most icon?

Comment: Perfect. I think I'll modify my answer to add an install/uninstall macro.